# Apple TestFlight: "this version is no longer available for testing"

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, beta-testing

I've been using TestFlight for my internal beta testings, everything was set and it was working for a while. after one of the submitted binaries got rejected from AppStore review, there seems to be a problem.
On any new uploaded binaries and turning on the Beta testing switch in iTunes Connect, I get the notification from testflight app that the new version is ready to be downloaded but on the app it says "UNAVAILABLE Expires in 30 days" and when I click on the beta app in TestFlight, on top it says "This version is no longer available for testing" even though the expire date is in a month from now.

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved this issue, not once but twice, apparently it's a bug.

what you have to do is turn off all the beta testings and then turn on the one you want to test, and then it works :)

Comment: Can you be more clear? What do you mean by "turn off all the beta testings"? Where? In iTunesConnect?

Comment: yes in iTunesConnect -> App

Comment: where i can see this options ?

Comment: @gamex you have to go to your app in itunesconnect and on the testflight tab. they changed the UI there so it might be different than what was described above.

Comment: @Shayanbahal Thanks for reply