# Unable to install the testflight build with "Developer certificate is no longer Valid" message

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I am facing a weird situation, the appstore upload were successful and were able to install the testflight build till yesterday. However since today it is showing "The app couldn't be installed because developer certificate is no longer valid". We have uploaded other projects yesterday with the same certificate. We tried regenerating the profile , but still the app cannot be installed from testflight and the weirdest situation is some users were able to install the app from testflight . Have anyone faced this situation? Is there a solution?

Comment: see this link may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866581/apple-testflight-this-version-is-no-longer-available-for-testing

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have faced same issue like you,

I **turned off all the beta testings** and then turn on the one which i want to test, and then it works.

**Note:-** Beta testing  iTunesConnect - App

Try this.

Comment: Hope for the best. Try it.

Comment: Then last option is  rebuilt using fresh certs and profiles

Answer (score 0):

Apple made certificate revoked,just delete certificate in your key-chain and download it again.

Comment: Maybe you should valid your profile and download at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have noticed that all your certificates in your Keychain show the error "This certificate has an invalid issuer".

To fix it follow these steps:
Open up Keychain Access.
Show expired certificates by going to View > Show Expired Certificates.
Navigate to the System keychain and delete the expired WWDR Certificate.
Download the new WWDR Certificate here and import it into your keychain.

Comment: Please check if the correct provision profiles are selected in the Targets for Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

In keychain access, -> Show Expired Certificates, then in your login keychain click on expired certificate and delete it. I also had the same expired certificate in my System keychain, so I deleted it from there too.

-> After deleting the expired cert from the login and System keychains,download certificate from below link and open with keychain.

Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and add it to Keychain access > certificates (which expires on 2023)

After this try to create new developer certificate and after this you can upload app for testing and this error will solved.

It worked for me.